# How to handle Unable to create call adapter for retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have created that BaseCallBack class as generic for retrofit but it throws that error:

> Unable to create call adapter

this is `BaseCallback.class`

```
public class BaseCallBack<T extends ResponseObject> implements Callback<BaseResponse<T>> {

public static final String TAG = BaseCallBack.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse<T>> call, Response<BaseResponse<T>> response) {
    if (checkInternet(response) && response.isSuccessful()) {
        verifyResponse(response.body());
        complete();
    } else if (!response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 401) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new UnAuthErrorEvent());
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse<T>> call, Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NoInternetEvent());
    } else {
        handleFail(t.getMessage());
    }
    complete();
}

protected boolean checkInternet(Response<BaseResponse<T>> response) {
    if (response.code() == DataHolder.NO_INTERNET) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NoInternetEvent());
        complete();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected void verifyResponse(BaseResponse<T> response) {
    if (response == null)
        handleFail((String) null);
    else
        handleSuccess(response.getData());
}

protected void handleSuccess(T response) {
    if (response != null)
        EventBus.getDefault().post(response);
}

protected void handleFail(BaseResponse response) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new FailEvent("failed"));
    if (response.getErrors() == 401) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new UnAuthErrorEvent());
    }
}

protected void handleFail(String message) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new FailEvent(message));
}

protected void complete() {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new CompleteEvent());
}
```

}

and this is `ResponseObject.class`:

```
public class ResponseObject extends BaseObservable {
}
```

and this is the interface for service

```
 @GET(ServicesHolder.specialities)
BaseCallBack<BaseResponse<DataObject<SpecialitiesDM>>> getSpecialities();
```

this how i call it

```
 specialitiesIService.getSpecialities();
```

I an using Dagger to inject the RETROFIT and the ServiceInterface when trying to make a call for the service just throw that error that I can't handle it till now, I have see a lot of answers but it was related to RxJava and I am not using RxJava in the app

Comment: When does it give you the error? Post the code and the error trace, please

Comment: give the error when calling the service

Comment: i have updated the question @JaviMollá

Comment: How are you building or initializing specialitiesIService?

Comment: dagger injection @JaviMollá

Comment: I guess that you're injecting the Retrofit dependency and then creating the service by calling retrofit.create(Specialities.class), isn't it?

Comment: yes, that how i create it

Comment: Post the complete error trace to see if there's any error that helps